# Why does enclosing the function name in parenthesis disable implicit declaration?

Tags: c, function, gcc

This is the construct in question:

```
int main (void)
{
    int a = 5;
    
    (func)(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with GNU GCC C99 the following will happen:

- If `func` was defined as a function before `main()` the function will be executed.
- If `func` was not defined as a function before `main` the compiler issues "func undeclared" error

However, if I remove the braces around `func` the function will be implicitly declared so even if it is defined in another translation unit, it will execute, which is the behavior I would always expect.

A recursive-descent parser identifies a function call expression (also according to the standard) by the presence of `(arguments)` which is why code like `3(a);` would issue an error: "called object is not a function or function pointer". And just like other similar operations such as the suffix increment, what comes before `(arguments)` is expected to be a subexpression - in this case the constraint demands an operand that is a function or a function pointer. With every other operation you can freely add as many brackets as you like: `((a))++` and that wouldn't change a thing, however with function calls it does not look quite like that.

Why would that code behave differently, is it a language feature that I didn't know of, or a result from some carefully crafted parsing design choice?

Comment: It seems the title asks a slightly different question than the question body. The good way to ban calling undeclared functions is with compiler flags.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am sorry and you may be right. I am very tired, sleepy and not a proficient English speaker. Could you recommend me a better title? I am indeed more interested into the technical details as I am writing a C99-compatible interpreter in GCC flavor.. :)

Comment: Yep, this is a better title.

Comment: "if I remove the braces around func the function will be implicitly declared" I can't reproduce that unless I force gcc into dinosaur `-std=c89` mode.

Comment: @Lundin You cannot reproduce the implicit function declaration? It yields the same result on my main compiler as well as onlinegdb, both compiling with gcc (-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror=shadow -std=c99). The warning is definitely expected.

Comment: But yeah I have no idea how to handle this in my own expression parser, unless I know what is actually happening and why maybe and then probably add a lot of code for a special treatment, but hopefully not.

Comment: I mean that `func(a);` only compiles cleanly with `-std=c89`. With every other compiler setting, I get an error and not just a warning, even with lax settings (not using -pedantic-errors).

Comment: @Lundin I always get a warning from the compiler, and of course the linker error if it was unable to find a definition.

Comment: @Edenia No with `func(a);` you get an _error_ with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror=shadow -std=c99` and no executable generated. So why are you claiming that it will execute? https://godbolt.org/z/rhnbs4sqa  (-Werror=shadow does nothing in this case)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256521/discussion-between-edenia-and-lundin).

Comment: @Lundin You'll get a linker error but just a warning from the compiler in anything besides the trunk version of gcc.

Comment: @dbush I was using gcc version 13.3 which gives an error for everything but `-std=c89`. I'm assuming this has to do with C23 removing non-prototype functions. clang behaves the same - warning instead of error up to the first version supporting C23, then error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of how implicit declarations were defined in C89.  Only a bare identifier qualifies as an implicit declaration.

This is spelled out in section 3.3.2.2 of the [C89 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c89/c89-draft.html):

> If the expression that precedes the parenthesized argument list in a
> function call consists solely of an identifier, and if no declaration
> is visible for this identifier, the identifier is implicitly declared
> exactly as if, in the innermost block containing the function call,
> the declaration
>
> ```
>      extern int  identifier();
> ```
>
> appeared.

Since in this case:

```
(func)(a);
```

The expression preceding the parenthesized arguments is not *just* an identifier, it does not qualify as an implicit declaration.

As for why gcc still seems to allow this even in C99 and later mode with `-pedantic`, I'd chalk that up to either an extension or a bug.

Comment: Oh :) Yes, I felt that reading the 1000-pages long C99 draft may not be sufficient to fully capture GNU C99 in its full grace.

Comment: Also this requirement is really very weird and I will not be able to sleep if I don't reason out why was it made this way.

Comment: @Edenia If `func` has not been declared as a function or function pointer, then `(func)(a);` looks like a cast expression statement.

Comment: @IanAbbott It does not (not to the compiler anyway), because a parser only identifies a type cast operator if the contents (in this case "func") constitute a valid type. If not then it treats it like an undeclared object inside parenthesizes as it is in this case.

Comment: @Edenia And it is only recognized as a function call if it has a valid type. All we can say is that it is invalid.

Comment: (func) is valid operand to "(argument_list)" i.e function call when `func` is declared as a function or a function pointer. The presence of parenthesizes do not make an expression invalid.